# How to run Powershell file with ODP dependency in background of C# console app?

Tags: c#, oracle, powershell

I've one PowerShell script file which contains ODP assembly to connect to oracle database. I want to run it in the background of C# console application then display the result in the C# console. This is the PowerShell script:-

```
Add-Type -path "C:\path\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"
$constr = "User Id=userxxx;Password=xxxx;Data Source=xxxx"
$conn= New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($constr)
$conn.Open()
$sql="SELECT A,B,C,D FROM XXXXX"
$command = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand( $sql,$conn)
$reader=$command.ExecuteReader()
$columnNames=$reader.GetSchemaTable() | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ColumnName
$resultSet=@()
while ($reader.Read()) {
    $result=New-Object object
        $result | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $columnNames[0] -NotePropertyValue $reader.GetDateTime(0)
        $result | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $columnNames[1] -NotePropertyValue $reader.GetDateTime(1)
        $result | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $columnNames[2] -NotePropertyValue $reader.GetDateTime(2)
        $result | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $columnNames[3] -NotePropertyValue $reader.GetDateTime(3)
    $resultSet += $result
}
$conn.Close()
$resultSet | Format-Table -AutoSize 
Read-Host -Prompt “Press Enter to exit”
```

I tried this code using C# to use the PowerShell script:-

```
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
runspace.Open();
RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
Command myCommand = new Command(@"C:\path\connectDB.ps1");
pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (PSObject obj in results)
{
    stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
}

Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

But I got this exception: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll`

And this is the message: `Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\path\Oracle.DataAccess.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an program with an incorrect format.`

How can I view the data, PowerShell file name, username and database used for this in the C# console screen?

Comment: Your powershell script uses *.NET* objects, specifically ADO.NET objects to connect to a database. Why don't you use that code in your console application? It's less code than what you tried already and safer - the powershell script don't check for errors and will leave the connection open in case of errors

Comment: Check the [OracleDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader?view=netframework-4.7.2) documentation. The example is exactly what the powershell script is trying to do in a verbose way. What do you want to do with the results? What do you want them to look like?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i'm actually trying to run a few PowerShell script files in the background of C# console and want to display kind of log of all the process like timestamp, PowerShell filename running, database used, it's user and final result success/not. But I'm taking my time to learn the integration of C# and PowerShell. That's why I don't directly used the code in console app.

Comment: That's not what is going on in this case. You aren't running a separate process, you are building and running a Powershell pipeline inside your own application. `in the background` may mean a separate process, which can be done with `Process.Start` or a separate thread in your own application.

Comment: As for building your own pipeline, Powershell differentiates between cmdlets, and scripts. You need to use [Commands.AddScript()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addscript?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) to load a script file. [Commands.AddCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addcommand?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) is used only for cmdlets. This is explained in [Adding and Invoking Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your explanation. sorry but I still try to understand here. so you mean the kind of logging that I want to display after run few PowerShell script files cannot be done using this code?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use Powershell at all. The Powershell script uses [ADO.NET objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/index) which are *easier* to use in C#. The documentation of the [OracleDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader?view=netframework-4.7.2) has an example that shows how to execute a query and read the results.

```
public void ReadData(string connectionString)
{
   string queryString = "SELECT A,B,C,D FROM XXXXX";
   using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
   {
       var command = new OracleCommand(queryString, connection);
       connection.Open();
       using(OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
       {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}",
                                 reader.GetDateTime(0),
                                 reader.GetDateTime(1),
                                 reader.GetDateTime(2),
                                 reader.GetDateTime(3));
           }
       }
  }
}
```

The question doesn't explain how the results will be used. Most likely, they won't be printed out.

One option is to use them in the loop itself. Another option is to load them in a DataTable by calling [DataTable.Load()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=netframework-4.7.2), eg

```
using(OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    var table=new DataTable();
    table.Load(reader);
    return table;
}
```

The DataTable will contain the columns and types returned by the reader.

ADO.NET was part of .NET since the beginning so it's *very* well covered in the documentation, courses, articles and tutorials.

Nowadays, it's much more common to load results directly into strongly typed objects using ORMs like Entity Framework or micro-ORMs like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). Assuming we have this class :

```
class MyResultClass
{
    public DateTime A {get;set;}
    public DateTime B {get;set;}
    public DateTime C {get;set;}
    public DateTime D {get;set;}
}
```

Dapper allows us to load a list of results with a simple :

```
string queryString = "SELECT A,B,C,D FROM XXXXX";
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    var results=connection.Query<MyResultClass>(queryString);
    return results;
}
```